# Re-using a partial view (ascx) across different Controllers and Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

Let's assume I have 2 Controllers, *TopicsController* and *PostsController*.

For each controller, I have a couple of views *(Index & Details).*

The ***Topic (Index)*** view inherits `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<MessageBoard.Models.Topic>>`

The **Topic (Details)** view inherits `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MessageBoard.Models.TopicFormViewModel>`
*I'm using a TopicFormViewModel because I'm sending additional data along with the Model.*

The **Post (Details)** view just inherits `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MessageBoard.Models.Post>`

Now, I've created a partial view ***(CreatePost.ascx)*** which is (obviously :p) used to create a new Post. I want to be able to re-use this control on all of the views you see above.

**Update**
I've tried rendering the partial view using `<% Html.RenderPartial("New"); %>` from my *Topics/Index.aspx* View, but that results in an exception

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Linq.Table`1[MessageBoard.Models.Topic]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MessageBoard.Models.Post'.

Now the problem is that my partial view ***(CreatePost.ascx)*** accepts a `System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MessageBoard.Models.Post>` and I'm not sure how to pass that from all my views above.

I'm also unsure know how to submit the .ascx values to a certain URL (i.e. /Topics/1/CreatePost), how do I tell the submit button to post to that URL?

Thanks in advance,
Marko

Comment: Erm, why the downvote? Someone's having a joke and downvoting my questions it seems.

Comment: what form elements does `CreatePost` have on it? Why is it of type `Post`? Isn't the point to create one from scratch, and thereby the post doesn't yet exist?

Comment: @p.campbell - you're right. The reason I was wanting to pass a Model was actually the fact that each post is associated with a Topic and I needed the ID so I can create the Post in the right place. I've now used ViewData to do this, and it seems to be working great. The only concern I have is having to pass ViewData from each controller Action that has an Add Post form on the page but I can handle this. It's my first project so still learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao Marko,

> Now the problem is that my partial
>   view (CreatePost.ascx) accepts a
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl
>   and I'm not sure how to pass that from
>   all my views above.

I am not sure I understand what do you mean by "*how to pass that from all my views above*" but I am sure that you dont have to pass an instance of Post from your views. What is going on is that from your views you will invoke a controller action that creates the Post model object and then bind it to the CreatePost.ascx partial.

> I'm also unsure know how to submit the
>   .ascx values to a certain URL (i.e.
>   /Topics/1/CreatePost), how do I tell
>   the submit button to post to that URL?

You have two options:

Inside your CreatePost.ascx partial you are probably using a form.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post, new {} )) { %>
```

If you use in the way I am showing you can change the first and the second params respectively to the names of the Action and the Controller that would habndle your submit.

The second option is using jQuery. Simply set an ID for your form and then

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
    //post an ajax request to the server
});
```

Hope this helps!

P.S. To be able to reuse your CreatePost.ascx partial place it inside the shared view folder (where your master page is).

Comment: Hi @Lorenzo, Thanks for the tips on `BeginForm`, I didn't know it accepts parameters so I've now fixed that. Cheers! Regarding the other issue, please see my update.

Comment: @Marko: If you do the RenderPartial from inside a view that is strong typed to a MyObject class, the framework will try to pass that instance of object to the RenderPartial method. But your partial is strong typed to another object... You should create an instance of a Post model and then do `<% Html.RenderPartial("CreatePost", myPostInstance); %>`

Comment: Anyway I want to warn you that creating instance of objects inside the views is not the right method...

Comment: please see my comment in reply to @p.campbell above. I'm gonna accept your answer now, cheers for the help!

Comment: @Marko: Ok! ViewData is a good way to handle the job. I have posted another answer that describe another method. Glad to know that helped in some way

Answer (score 0):

In regards to reusing a partial view which is not in the same view folder, use the following and pass in the model required, alternatively you can define a custom route for it.

```
<% html.RenderPartial("~/Views/<ControllerName>/<PartialViewName>.ascx", <model>);
```

Comment: Hey @Dien, my issue is related to passing the model to the RenderPartial, not to finding the Partial View itself :)

Comment: Sure, no problem. I'm sure you know this but you can pass the model as a parameter to the partial view.

Answer (score 0):

@Marko

Another way would be to have in the PostController an Action like the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreatePost( int topicId ) {
    PostModel pm = _manager.CreateDefaultPost();
    pm.TopicID = id;
    return PartialView( "CreatePost", pm );
}
```

Then wherever you want to create a Post you can simply call this action that returns the strong-typed view for your new post.

Even if you have a supplementary http call over the network IMO this solution has the advantage to keep the initialization code of a new Post centralized to a single place.

From the View "point-of-view" the call to the action can be done when the user press the "New Post" button and then inject the received markup inside a modal dialog or in a place of your pleasure in the current page.

Hope it helps!